# Basic Case : System will call person A. If person A picks up the phone it will call person B and the 2 will be connected

Tags: node.js, twilio

```
   const accountSid = 'ACf36...'
   const authToken = '094...'
   const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken)
   const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;

   client = Client()

   twiml = VoiceResponse()
   twiml.dial('+912345674127')
   call = client.calls.create(
    from_ = '+14809078750',
    to = '+916395545354',
    twiml = str(twiml),
   )
   console.log(call)
```

I am trying to make a confrence call using this code and dial function of twilio, but this does not seem to work.
One person successfully joins the room, but 2nd person is not getting call to join the conference.

Comment: From Twilio's Docs: `You can initiate an outbound call by POSTing to the Call resource, creating a new call. You can also initiate a call from an active call (e.g., forwarding to another number or dialing into a conference) by including TwiML’s <Dial> verb in your TwiML application. However, the only way to initiate a call directly from Twilio is with an API request.`

References: 
 * https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource
 * https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#examples-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First up, it looks as though you included your Account SID and Auth Token in your question. Those credentials give full access to your account and posting them publicly means anyone who comes across them can use them to abuse your account. Please do not do this in the future and [**change your auth token** using this process](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136027-Auth-Tokens-and-How-to-Change-Them).

Now, the code you've posted isn't far from being correct for connecting two people in a call. The `console.log` will not log the call object though, as the result of `client.calls.create` is a Promise that resolves to a call. Also, `str` is not a JavaScript function.

Try the following:

```js
const twilio = require('twilio');
const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);
const VoiceResponse = twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse;

const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
twiml.dial('+912345674127');

client.calls.create({
  from: '+14809078750',
  to: '+916395545354',
  twiml: twiml.toString()
})
  .then(call => {
    console.log(call);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

If you want to create a conference call, where more than 2 people can join, then you have a bit more work to do. In a conference call the conference acts as a room that people join. So when one person connects to the conference you need to generate a new outbound call using the API to connect another person to the conference. There is a tutorial on [how to create conference calls with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-create-conference-calls-node-js) that I recommend you go through.

Comment: I used above code which you provided but  there is a type error

Comment: twiml = twiml.toString(),
        ^

TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

Comment: Argh, that code looks like it was a mix of Python and JavaScript. I've corrected it now, so it should work for JavaScript now. I've edited my answer, try again :)

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome! And if the answer helped, please do mark it as correct so that others can see it was useful too. Thanks!